# What class of functions can bound the distance from its zero-set by its value?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have the following question:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Is there any class of functions and some kind of "growth conditions" such that bounds like below can be established:
\begin{equation}
||f(x)||\geq g\left( \text{dist}(x,\mathcal{X})\right),
\end{equation}
with $\mathcal{X}$ := $\{x:f(x)=0\}$ (zero set of $f$) and some function $g$ (e.g. $\ell 2$-norm).

I am interested to know the class of functions. A trivial (stupid!) example is $f(x)=x$ with $g$ being the  $\ell 2$-norm . Any help will help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did a research and I want to share the answer: Luo-Tseng error bounds and related subjects like quadratic growth conditions, ...